# How to stop method running multiple times from multiple api requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, api

I am working on an end point that needs to refresh an auth token.
The front end calls this method multiple times a second (one for each instance where it realises that auth is needed)

In the back I have a method that is called by the api:

```
def get_refresh_token(self)
    body = "token=123LastRefreshToken"
    response = requests.post(url, headers, data=body)

    self.update_auth(response)
    return self.save_new_refesh_token(response)
```

How can I stop this from executing if a request is in progress. The issue is that if one of the requests resolves after last one sent I will be saving an invalid token (not the last one generated)

Comment: Sounds like you need to implement some sort of request queue

Answer (score 0):

Run a `redis` instance and make a queue in it. All requests for new refresh token should append its ID into the queue; and when you run this `get_refresh_token` method, check if it is the first one in the queue and if it is not, run `sleep(0.1)` and try again:

```py
def get_refresh_token(self)
    while it is not the first one in redis queue:
        time.sleep(0.1)

    pop the id from redis queue

    body = "token=123LastRefreshToken"
    response = requests.post(url, headers, data=body)

    self.update_auth(response)
    return self.save_new_refesh_token(response)
```

I would rather use an async way with `await asyncio.sleep(0.1)` instead of this synchronous one. Because the whole thread will be stopped in order to wait to be the first one in queue.